# Handling images with php

Tags: php, image

I saw on internet a piece of php code to handle images, it goes like this:

```
$directory="books";

$dirint = dir($directory);

while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
{

if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo))
  {
    echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'">'."\n";
  }
}

$dirint->close();
```

The thing is that the code works ok if directory "books" is in the same directory as the php file, but I tried changing directory "books" to another directory, let´s say `C:\Users\User` and when I run the php file I get the following error:

> Warning: dir(books): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Course\galeria.php on line 16

I´m beginning to believe that I can´t move the images directory, it has to be in the same directory as the php file.

Can anyone confirm this or I´m wrong and I´m not using the right path to point to the right directory?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: `it goes like this` made my day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug this by using the php function `getcwd()`

Can you try using

```
$dirint = dir(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $directory);
```

(also not that `eregi()` is deprecated and has been replaced by `preg_match()`)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Kevin. I changed the eregi() for preg_match() and I also changed the images file path (instead of using "\" as a path delimeter I used "/"), but still don´t see my images. It is as if the code line: 'echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'">'."\n";' is not right!

Answer (score 0):

> I´m beginning to believe that I can´t move the images directory, it
>   has to be in the same directory as the php file.
>
> Can anyone confirm this?

No. Changing the directory should not be a problem, but you have to make sure it exists and your PHP code references the correct path.

If you move the directory `books` to another path, you have to adjust your variable:

```
$directory = 'C:\Users\User\books';
```

Keep in mind you have to change this if you ever plan to run the script on a different machine, especially on Linux. You might want to create a config file for the definition of this path.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Pharaoh. I did as you suggested (I set variable $directory to "C:\Users\User\books";) and the system returned this error massege: Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Course\galeria.php on line 23

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I made a mistake. The comment was for kevin.coyle.